# How do I put a cross on variation of a product that are out of stock?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a cross on the variation which are out of stock.

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i have tried few plugins but that doesn't work properly.

Comment: OK, but this is not how StackOverflow works .. this site is about coding and helping with the code when you're stuck. This is more like a question for Facebook Woocommerce groups where people share info about adding functionality through plugins

Comment: well, yes i am looking forward to do some coding if required ! Any guidance will be appreciated.